# Puzzling "reduction too large" error

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase

I have a document bucket with the following format:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4,
  "e": 5
}
```

This is my mapping function:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  var summary = {
    b: doc.b,
    c: doc.c,
    history: [{
      d: doc.d,
      e: doc.e
    }]
  };
  emit(doc.a, summary);
}
```

And here's my reduce function:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  for (i = 1; i < values.length; ++i)
    Array.prototype.push.apply(values[0].history, values[i].history);
  return values[0];
}
```

And finally, here are my view query parameters:

```
?stale=false&group=true&reduce=true
```

This combination leads to a `reduction too large` error. For now, I have at most 2 of the same keys in my dataset, so I can change the reduce function to:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  if (values[1])
    Array.prototype.push.apply(values[0].history, values[1].history);
  return values[0];
}
```

Keeping everything else the same, I get the exact result that I want:

```
{  
   "key":1,
   "value":{  
      "b":2,
      "c":3,
      "history":[  
         {  
            "d":4,
            "e":5
         },
         {  
            "d":6,
            "e":7
         }
      ]
   }
}, many more like this
```

However, I expect the number of keys to grow over time, so I need to be able to loop over `values`.

I also changed my reduce function to simply return `values.length` in order to check if it was returning unreasonable values, but everything I get is either `1` or `2`.

What is going on?

**UPDATE:**

When I change my reduce function to:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) return "whatisgoingon";
  for (i = 1; i < values.length; ++i)
    Array.prototype.push.apply(values[0].history, values[i].history);
  return values[0];
}
```

I get the results that I desire, however `whatisgoingon` is nowhere to be found in the view result. I don't want to "discard" the rereduce logic since I might actually use it in the future, so I need to understand the cause of the issue.

Comment: rereduce is mandatory, you have to implement it. Have you read http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/developer-guide/views-writing.html#story-h2-8 ?

Comment: My reduce and rereduce cases use the same logic, so it is not strictly mandatory to implement a seperate rereduce flow. As I've said, I get correct results by using my static array index example, which has no rereduce flow.